# SQL Server "FOR JSON AUTO" Excluding Column Names

Tags: sql-server, json, sql-server-2016

I have a SQL Server 2016 query that returns the results in JSON format using the `FOR JSON AUTO` clause.

It returns the following (line break added for readability's sake):

```
[{"Count":0},{"Count":0},{"Count":0},{"Count":0},{"Count":36},{"Count":25},
 {"Count":22},{"Count":22},{"Count":1},{"Count":13},{"Count":0},{"Count":1}]
```

I'm however wanting it to return the data minus the `"Count"` column name.

Is this possible? As it's a new feature, I haven't been able to find much documentation on this.

Comment: Show sample data and the actual query you ran against it.

Comment: Or just hack around it and replace "Count": with a blank.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just dealing with the JSON result-data through .NET core code and it worked well.